# Segfault when calling functor or function pointer

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, function-pointers, functor

I have a class which can create urls, and thread which asks instances for urls and runs them with curl (thread managed by static members of the class, instances are added to the list, etc, omitted for readability as that's not the issue). The code is compiled with g++12 and std20 via VS remote development.

```
class Downloader
{
public:
    using ParseCb = std::function<bool(const std::string&)>;
    //typedef bool (*ParseCb)(const std::string&);

private:
    ParseCb parse_cb;

public:
    Downloader(ParseCb);
    virtual ~Downloader();

protected:
    bool parse_data(const std::string&);
    virtual const std::string get_url() = 0;
};
```

From this class several others are derived, each implementing their own `get_url()` (which is called by the worker thread, executed, and the content returned into the `parse_data`). They inherit the constructor with `using Downloader::Downloader;`.

One of my callback functions has following declaration:

```
bool parse_my_json(const std::string& json);
```

And used like so:

```
DownloaderDerived dldr(parse_my_json);
```

```
Downloader::Downloader(ParseCb p) : parse_cb(p)
{
 // ...
}
```

Now the implementation of `parse_data`:

```
bool Downloader::parse_data(const std::string& data)
{
    cout << "Parsing data: " << endl;
    cout << data << endl; // prints properly

    std::string xd = R"({"status":"ok","meta":{"count":1},"data":{"0":null}})";

    return parse_cb(data); // segfault
    //return parse_cb(xd); // segfault
    //return parse_my_json(data); // works properly
}
```

Following segfault occurs with functor:

```
    [Unknown/Just-In-Time compiled code]    
>   std::function<bool (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)>::operator()(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const(const std::function<bool(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)> * const this,  __args#0) Line 591  C++
    Downloader::parse_data(Downloader * const this, const std::string & data) Line 82   C++
    Downloader::downloader_callback(Server srv) Line 236    C++
    std::__invoke_impl<void, void (*)(Server), Server>(void (*&)(Server) __f) Line 61   C++
    std::__invoke<void (*)(Server), Server>(void (*&)(Server) __fn) Line 96 C++
    std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(Server), Server> >::_M_invoke<0ul, 1ul>(std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(Server), Server> > * const this) Line 252   C++
    std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(Server), Server> >::operator()(std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(Server), Server> > * const this) Line 259    C++
    std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(Server), Server> > >::_M_run(std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(Server), Server> > > * const this) Line 210  C++
    libstdc++.so.6![Unknown/Just-In-Time compiled code] 
    libc.so.6!start_thread(void * arg) Line 442 C
    libc.so.6!clone3() Line 81  C++
```

in the `std_function.h`:
[image: header code segfault]

If I use function pointer instead of a functor, I get similar segfault:

```
    [Unknown/Just-In-Time compiled code]    
>   Downloader::parse_data(Downloader * const this, const std::string & data) Line 82   C++
    Downloader::downloader_callback(Server srv) Line 236    C++
    std::__invoke_impl<void, void (*)(Server), Server>(void (*&)(Server) __f) Line 61   C++
    std::__invoke<void (*)(Server), Server>(void (*&)(Server) __fn) Line 96 C++
    std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(Server), Server> >::_M_invoke<0ul, 1ul>(std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(Server), Server> > * const this) Line 252   C++
    std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(Server), Server> >::operator()(std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(Server), Server> > * const this) Line 259    C++
    std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(Server), Server> > >::_M_run(std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(Server), Server> > > * const this) Line 210  C++
    libstdc++.so.6![Unknown/Just-In-Time compiled code] 
    libc.so.6!start_thread(void * arg) Line 442 C
    libc.so.6!clone3() Line 81  C++
```

As for the *n.m.*'s question, `this` is `0x7ffff0000090`, what is weird, this pointer is not the same value as the pointer in the list of instances... `parse_my_json` is `0x5555555ccafb`.
`this->parse_cb` is `0x7ffff00db700` in case of function pointer and in case of functor:

```
-       parse_cb        Downloader::ParseCb
-       std::_Maybe_unary_or_binary_function<bool, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&> (base)   std::_Maybe_unary_or_binary_function<bool, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>  std::_Maybe_unary_or_binary_function<bool, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>
        std::unary_function<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool> (base)    std::unary_function<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool>   std::unary_function<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool>
-       std::_Function_base (base)  std::_Function_base std::_Function_base
        _M_max_size 16  const std::size_t
        _M_max_align    8   const std::size_t
+       _M_functor      std::_Any_data
        _M_manager  0x7ffff00d5490  std::_Function_base::_Manager_type
        _M_invoker  0x7ffff0078f10  std::function<bool(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)>::_Invoker_type
```

For the functor, the inner scope variables are:

```
+       this    {bool (std::_Any_data &, const std::_Any_data &, std::_Manager_operation)} 0x7ffff00d5490   const std::function<bool(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)> * const
        __args#0    -var-create: unable to create variable object
```

I have no idea what is going on. Am I using function pointers/functors wrong? I've been unable to reproduce it on a smaller example, this is already dumbed down as much as possible. Does it havve something to do with forwarding `const&`?

Comment: nowhere in the code you posted you assign something to `parse_cb`. It is an empty `std::function`. Calling it can segfault.

Comment: what function do you expect `return parse_cb(data);` to call? and why?

Comment: Can we get a [mre]?  `return parse_cb(data);` could leave you with a dangling reference to `data` depending on how it was passed to `parse_data`

Comment: Unrelated: Returning a `const std::string` is pointless. Either return a `const&` or just return it by value.

Comment: Initialize your callback: `ParseCb parse_cb{[](const std::string&){ return false }};`

Comment: You have a debugger, might as well use it. In `Downloader::parse_data`, what is the value of `this`? of `*this`? of `this->parse_cb`?

Comment: I imagine it's a dangling reference in `parse_cb` but since no posted code shows how that is initialised it's only a guess.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I forgot to add it. It is assigned in the constructor. Updated the question.

Comment: @NathanOliver what do you mean about the dangling reference?

Comment: @n.m. Added the values you asked about. None of them are null.

Comment: "this is 0x7ffff0000090, this->parse_cb is 0x7ffff00db700 in case of function pointer" This doesn't look good to me. What is the address of `parse_my_json`? This should be the value of `this->parse_cb`.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, somehow the address is completely different, `this->parse_cb = 0x7ffff007b040`, `parse_my_json = 0x5555555ccafb`. So there must be something wrong with the constructor or assignment?

Comment: There is something wrong between object creation and object use, what it could be is something I cannot possibly guess.

Comment: @n.m. Solved... I forgot to set the `owner` when adding requests to the queue and it just used an uninitialized pointer as a bogus object, and then segfaulted when trying to reach "its" "parse_cb"...
Why didn't it segfault immediately when calling `owner->parse_data` ?
If you add an answer consisting of your comments, I could accept it.

Comment: An unitialised pointer doesn't necessarily mean an immediate crash.

Comment: `return parse_cb ? parse_cb(data) : false;`